# Can't do a pull request after rebase

Tags: git, github

I created first-branch and added several commits to it. While on first-branch, I rebased it and pushed it. However, I can't create a pull request on GitHub to merge the first-branch to the master branch. I just get a message saying there is nothing to compare and they are different commit histories.

```
git rebase -i --root
git push origin first-branch --force
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not rebase using `--root`, which will rebase all commits in `master` **and** `first-branch`. If you rebase without `--root`, git will only rebase the commits that are in `first-branch` but not in `master`.

Instead you should have done

```
git checkout first-branch
git rebase -i master
git push origin first-branch --force
```